# Recover data in a string with fixed positions

Tags: php, regex, optimization

I have a file that contains data at fixed positions (no separator).

for exemple:

```
$string = '0412345678Mr foo    25.2';
```

with

```
code  = '04'       (integer with 2 characters)
ref   = '12345678' (string  with 8 characters)
name  = 'Mr foo  ' (string  with 8 characters)
price = '  25.2'   (double  with 6 characters)
```

I can do that:

```
$code  = (int) substr($string, 0, 2);
$ref   = substr($string, 2, 8);
$name  = substr($string, 10, 8);
$price = (double) substr($string, 18, 6);
```

It's work fine.

I would like to know if there is an another to do this.

I try that:

```
list($code, $ref, $name, $price) = sscanf($string, "%2d%8s%8s%6s");
```

But that don't work.

If I replace spaces with another character like `_`, that's work but I don't want change data.

Another Idea? Regular expression?

Comment: _Rule 10:_ If it aint broke, dont fix it!

Comment: You could do that by  using regular expression as you mention. 
`([0-9]{2})([0-9]{8})([a-zA-Z ]{8})([0-9. ]{6})` https://regex101.com/r/2bS8af/1

Comment: @kaldoran: I try that, but I don't know how to put result in variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned it, you could use regexp.
Here is an example of a simple one that would work :

```
([0-9]{2})([0-9]{8})([a-zA-Z ]{8})([0-9. ]{6})
```

https://regex101.com/r/2bS8af/1

With the addition of http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php, that could do the trick.

Then if you want them inside your variable simple assign them by taking the output of preg_match :)

```
<?php
$string = '0412345678Mr foo    25.2';

$pattern = '/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{8})([a-zA-Z ]{8})([0-9. ]{6})/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

By the way, you can replace [0-9] by "\d" etc ...
Which could give :

```
(\d{2})(\d{8})([\w\s]{8})([\d\s.]{6})
```

https://regex101.com/r/2bS8af/3

Comment: Thank you, I had test `preg_split` but not `preg_match`

Comment: No problem :) I've added a simpler version by using \d, \w etc :)

Comment: THks very much :)